# how to show current directory in ipython prompt

Tags: python, ipython, prompt

Is there is way to show the current directory in IPython prompt?

```
Instead of this:
In [1]:

Something like this:
In<~/user/src/proj1>[1]:
```

Comment: for showing current working directory you can use pwd command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're interested in configuring this for all subsequent invocations of ipython, run the following (in a traditional shell, like bash :) ). It appends to your default ipython configuration, creating it if necessary. The last line of the configuration file will also automatically make all the executables in your $PATH available to simply run in python, which you probably also want if you're asking about cwd in the prompt. So you can run them without a ! prefix. Tested with IPython 7.18.1.

```
mkdir -p ~/.ipython/profile_default
cat >> ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py <<EOF

from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
import os

class MyPrompt(Prompts):
    def cwd(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        if cwd.startswith(os.environ['HOME']):
            cwd = cwd.replace(os.environ['HOME'], '~')
            cwd_list = cwd.split('/')
            for i,v in enumerate(cwd_list):
                if i not in (1,len(cwd_list)-1): #not last and first after ~
                    cwd_list[i] = cwd_list[i][0] #abbreviate
            cwd = '/'.join(cwd_list)
        return cwd

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
        return [
                (Token.Prompt, 'In ['),
                (Token.PromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
                (Token.Prompt, '] '),
                (Token, self.cwd()),
                (Token.Prompt, ': ')]

c.TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class = MyPrompt
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%rehashx']
EOF
```

(c.PromptManager only works in older versions of ipython.)

Comment: This gave me a couple of errors in version 8.20.0. :(

Answer (score 83):

You can use `os.getcwd`(current working directory) or in the native os command `pwd`.

```
In [8]: import os

In [9]: os.getcwd()
Out[9]: '/home/rockwool'

In [10]: pwd
Out[10]: '/home/rockwool'
```

Comment: I know these commands, but is it possible to show them in the prompt, so I don't have to type every time?

Answer (score 11):

Using ! before pwd will show the current directory

```
In[1]: !pwd
/User/home/
```

When interactive computing it is common to need to access the underlying shell. This is doable through the use of the exclamation mark ! (or bang) To execute a command when present in beginning of line.

Comment: pwd is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @KansaiRobot you're probably in MS Windows in cmd.exe shell, in which case `cd` should do the same thing as pwd.  So in IPython, do `!cd`.

Answer (score 6):

According to:

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/details.html#specific-config-details

> In the terminal, the format of the input and output prompts can be customised. This does not currently affect other frontends.

So, in `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`, put something like:

```
c.PromptManager.in_template = "In<{cwd} >>>"
```

Comment: Is it possible to only show the last directory? Can I write a custom function on cwd like split?

Comment: I love this suggestion, but it seems to be out of date. `UserWarning: As of IPython 5.0 PromptManager config will have no effect and has been replaced by TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class`. Going to go try to hunt down where to make this change.

Answer (score 1):

`!dir` shows the current directory and the contained files. The directory is shown with single backslashes, that simplifies the handling of the path (at least when using windows).