# How to get output of OS command from Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, jupyter

I am running Jupyter notebook on a server (python 3).

Want to see output of OS command (any OS command - this is just example):

```
output = os.system("pwd")
```

When I do print of it:

```
print (output)
```

Response is `0`.

How to get a simple output (like in CLI)?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show current directory in ipython promp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481506/how-to-show-current-directory-in-ipython-promp)

Comment: This link is not correct. Question is in general to get OS output in iPython (not just PWD or CWD commands)..

Answer (score 8):

Just found it on internet and wanted to post.

It needs to be:

`print(os.popen('ls').read())`

(or any other OS command).

This works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
print(os.system("pwd"))
```

But this question is a duplicate:
[how to show current directory in ipython promp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481506/how-to-show-current-directory-in-ipython-promp)

Comment: `print(os.system("pwd"))` gives response as `0`.

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` works fine (can see expected output). Just need that `os.system` response (and not `0`)..

Comment: Yes, I added the os.system to show this output in comparison to the os.getcwd.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `os.system()` calls are not the preferred way to run any commands and do not ensure capturing the output (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for more on this).

The preferred and safer mechanism which **will** capture the output of commands is `subprocess.run()` which has a `capture_output` parameter and returns a `CompletedProcess` [object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) that has members including `stdout` and `stderr` which, if `capture_output=True` contain the output stream contents.

It is worth mentioning that for portability it is usually better to use the methods from the os, shutil, path & glob libraries, etc. This is because calls such as `ls`, `pwd`, `dir`, etc., will work on some platforms but not others.

Example:

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['cwd',], capture_output=True)
# Returns the current directory as a string for processing in result.stdout on Mac/Linux but raises an exception on Windows
print(result.stdout)
result = subprocess.run(['ls', '*.docx'], capture_output=True)
# Returns the *.docx files in the current directory as a string for processing in result.stdout on Mac/Linux but raises an exception on Windows
print(result.stdout)
```

However:

```
import pathlib
cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd() # Returns the current directory as a Path object on any platform.
print(cwd)
docs = cwd.glob('*.docx') # Returns an generator giving path for to any docx files in cwd on any platform
print(', '.join(p.name for p in docs)) # Print comma seperated list of filenames
```

Note that for long running or very verbose calls it is often better to use the subprocess.POpen constructor and `communicate` or `wait`.

If you want to start an external process and **not** wait for it to finish then use the [asynco](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_exec) `create_subprocess_exec()` call instead.